# Img Css Percentage in UIWebView with NSString

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview, nsstring

Hello i need to set CSS style in my HTML NSString to fit size of image in `UIWeView`.

Here is codes.

```
NSString *cssCode = @"img{max-width:100%}body{font-family:Custom-One;color:white;font-size:15px;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px black;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}";

NSString *myCustomString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>%@</style></head><body><b><font color=red><center> [ %@ ]</center></b><br/><b><center>[ Title ]</center> </font></b><br/>%@<body></html>",cssCode,[self.app stripTags:mmObject.title],myData];

[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:myCustomString baseURL:nil];
```

It doesn't work with `max-width:100%`. I think the percentage sign is the problem.
 How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

% will not work if you are writing this code in any view controller you have to use px;(pixels). If you are using .js file in your app and if you write % in .js file it will work.

Answer (score 1):

What you have will work fine if you escape the `\%` in your css string.

```
NSString *cssCode = @"img{max-width:100\%}body{font-family:Custom-One;color:white;font-size:15px;text-shadow:1px 1px 2px black;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}";
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody needs some more elegant solution, I did create a wrapper for SWIFT. https://github.com/Vanyaslav/Swiftyyjsformatter to format UIWebView text on iOS.